# python3 fastest way to calculate values from sqlite3 table and add as new column

Tags: python-3.x, performance, sqlite, database-performance, yield

I have a large (10 million entries) `sqlite3` table `myTable` with a column `myColumn` and a `python3` function `myFunction` to crunch some numbers. I would like to add a new column `resultColumn` to that same table, containing  the result of `myFunction` applied to the values in `myColumn`.
In python3 pseudocode:

```
input_values = get_sql_result('select myColumn from myTable')
result_values = myFunction(input_values)
execute_sql('alter table myTable add column resultColumn values=?', result_values)
```

But this seems quite slow because this requires 3 sequential operations on 10 million entries. What is the fastest way to do this? Perhaps using `yield` somehow?

Comment: One approach worth looking into: Add a user-defined sqlite function that does the number crunching, and then after adding the new column, use it in an update: `UPDATE my_table SET new_column = myfunc(existing_column)` or whatever. IIRC the python sqlite bindings make adding functions pretty easy to do.

Comment: Good tip, that's actually an answer to the question i wrote. Unfortunately in reality I have a function, which returns multiple values (which should be put into multiple columns) and this is not supported by sqlite3. Thanks though!